# Problem in getting User Profile Information from Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am facing a problem in getting the User Profile Information from Firebase.

Actually, I created a function which will get the user information from Firebase. The codes for the same is shown below-

```
function showProfileInformation(){
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user != null) {
    user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
      var storeTheEmail= profile.email;
      console.log(storeTheEmail);
    });
  }
}
```

When I call this function from **body tag** of the HTML as-

```
<body onload="showProfileInformation()">
```

Then, the function is called but It is not retrieving the User Information

But when I call this Function through a button, as-

```
<button onclick="showProfileInformation()">Click Me</button>
```

Then it works properly.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by delaying the execution of your function-

```
<body id="bodyTag" onload="changeTheStatusWithDelay()">

<script>


// IT IS THE FUNCTION WHICH WILL BE CALLED FROM BODY TAG

function changeTheStatusWithDelay(){


// IT WILL DELAY YOUR EXECUTION OF THE FUNCTION
setTimeout(changeItNow, 2000);

}

//NOW YOU CAN PASTE ALL OF YOUR CODE HERE

function changeItNow(){

var database = firebase.database();
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user != null) {




user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
var storeTheEmail= profile.email;
console.log(storeTheEmail);



});
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: No Problem. I am happy I could help you

Comment: Is there not a better way than this? Can you not tell it to wait for something before running your function, instead of waiting a fixed length of time and hoping for the best?

Comment: I couldn't find another way.
Can you suggest something?

Comment: No, I don't know anything about firebase. But I'd be surprised if there wasn't a way.

Comment: I know this solution is not that much worthy, but I am also new to Firebase, If anyone finds the solution, they are most welcome, because it doesn't work on slow network

Comment: How about this: `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { if (user != null) { ... } });` I think this should work, according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start .

Comment: it won't work on refreshing the page.
Think If the user is already logged and refreshes the page, then what? It won't work because the auth is not changed

Comment: Does it not rerun all the javascript when you refresh? If not, maybe there's some other event you could listen to for refreshes.

Comment: yes, it reruns all the javascript when I refresh it. But then also it is taking the same time to retrieve the information from Firebase.